# I can't locate a reocurring element from a bs4 object

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

The issue I am having is driving me crazy. I am trying to pull text from the Pro Football Reference website.

The information I need is in a `td` element displaying `qb hurries` In the second section of the web page. The information is in a td element called `qb_hurry`. Here is what I have so far:

```
res = requests.get('https://www.pro-football-reference.com/players/D/DonaAa00.htm')

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
```

I tried

```
totalQbHurrys = soup.find('div', {'id':'all_detailed_defense'})
```

and I can see the information I need to pull when I parse through the beautiful soup object and print it. But when I try to retrieve the `td` element I need

```
totalQbHurrys = soup.find('div', {'id':'all_detailed_defense'}).find('td', {'data-stat':'qb_hurry'})
```

it returns `None`, I think the text I am looking for exists as a comment first, but I am having trouble getting to the actual HTML element I need. Would anyone know of a way to target the `qb_hurry` element successfully?

Comment: what is the desired output ?

Comment: The desired output is the value inside of the td tag. So 32.

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified this earlier but I need the 2019 statistic so 32.

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that this field is inside HTML comment tag.

Here is a resolution :

```
import bs4
import requests

res = requests.get('https://www.pro-football-reference.com/players/D/DonaAa00.htm')

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')

extract = soup.find('div', {'id':'all_detailed_defense'})

for comments in extract.find_all(text=lambda text:isinstance(text, bs4.Comment)):
    comments.extract()

soup2 = bs4.BeautifulSoup(comments, 'html.parser')

totalQbHurrys = soup2.find('td', {'data-stat':'qb_hurry'})

print(totalQbHurrys)
```

PS: I have used this trick : https://stackoverflow.com/a/52874885/2186074

Answer (score 0):

The HTML you need is inside a comment so will not be directly visible in the `soup`. You need to first grab the comment and then parse this as a new `soup` object. From this you can then locate the `tr` and `th` elements. For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment
import requests

res = requests.get('https://www.pro-football-reference.com/players/D/DonaAa00.htm')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
div = soup.find('div', {'id':'all_detailed_defense'})
comment_html = div.find(string=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment))
comment_soup = BeautifulSoup(comment_html, 'html.parser')

for tr in comment_soup.find_all('tr'):
    row = [td.text for td in tr.find_all(['td', 'th'])]
    print(row)
```

Giving you:

```
['', 'Games', 'Pass Coverage', 'Pass Rush', 'Tackles']
['Year', 'Age', 'Tm', 'Pos', 'No.', 'G', 'GS', 'Int', 'Tgt', 'Cmp', 'Cmp%', 'Yds', 'Yds/Cmp', 'Yds/Tgt', 'TD', 'Rat', 'DADOT', 'Air', 'YAC', 'Bltz', 'Hrry', 'QBKD', 'Sk', 'Prss', 'Comb', 'MTkl', 'MTkl%']
['2018*+', '27', 'LAR', 'DT', '99', '16', '16', '0', '1', '0', '0.0%', '0', '', '0.0', '0', '39.6', '-2.0', '0', '0', '0', '30', '19', '20.5', '70', '59', '6', '9.2%']
['2019*+', '28', 'LAR', 'DT', '99', '16', '16', '0', '0', '0', '', '0', '', '', '0', '', '', '0', '0', '0', '32', '9', '12.5', '55', '48', '6', '11.1%']
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
import pandas as pd

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)

driver.get("https://www.pro-football-reference.com/players/D/DonaAa00.htm")

df = pd.read_html(driver.page_source, attrs={
                  'class': 'row_summable sortable stats_table now_sortable'}, header=1)[0]

print(df.loc[1, 'Hrry'])

driver.quit()
```

Output:

```
32
```