# Getting Table Info From Page Using Python and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

The page I am trying to get info from is https://www.pro-football-reference.com/teams/crd/2017_roster.htm.

I'm trying to get all the information from the "Roster" table but for some reason I can't get it through BeautifulSoup.I've tried `soup.find("div", {'id': 'div_games_played_team'})` but it doesn't work. When I look at the page's HTML I can see the table inside a very large comment and in a regular div. How can I use BeautifulSoup to get the information from this table?

Comment: check [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61141984/i-cant-locate-a-reocurring-element-from-a-bs4-object/61146440#61146440)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need Selenium. What you can do (and you correctly identified it), was pull out the comments, and then parse the table from within that.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import Comment
import pandas as pd


url = 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/teams/crd/2017_roster.htm'
response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
comments = soup.find_all(string=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment))

tables = []
for each in comments:
    if 'table' in each:
        try:
            tables.append(pd.read_html(each)[0])
        except ValueError as e:
            print(e)
            continue
```

**Output:**

```
print(tables[0].head().to_string())
    No.           Player   Age  Pos   G   GS     Wt    Ht  College/Univ  BirthDate   Yrs   AV                            Drafted (tm/rnd/yr)      Salary
0  54.0  Bryson Albright  23.0  NaN   7  0.0  245.0   6-5    Miami (OH)  3/15/1994     1  0.0                                            NaN    $246,177
1  36.0    Budda Baker*+  21.0   ss  16  7.0  195.0  5-10    Washington  1/10/1996  Rook  9.0     Arizona Cardinals / 2nd / 36th pick / 2017    $465,000
2  64.0    Khalif Barnes  35.0  NaN   3  0.0  320.0   6-6    Washington  4/21/1982    12  0.0  Jacksonville Jaguars / 2nd / 52nd pick / 2005    $176,471
3  41.0   Antoine Bethea  33.0   db  15  6.0  206.0  5-11        Howard  7/27/1984    11  4.0   Indianapolis Colts / 6th / 207th pick / 2006  $2,000,000
4  28.0    Justin Bethel  27.0  rcb  16  6.0  200.0   6-0  Presbyterian  6/17/1990     5  3.0    Arizona Cardinals / 6th / 177th pick / 2012  $2,000,000
....
```

Answer (score 0):

The tag you are trying to scrape is dynamically generated by JavaScript. You are most likely using requests to scrape your HTML. Unfortunately requests will not run JavaScript because it pulls all the HTML in as raw text. BeautifulSoup can not find the tag because it was never generated within your scraping program.

I recommend using [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/). It's not a perfect solution - just the best one for your problem. The Selenium WebDriver will execute the JavaScript to generate the page's HTML. Then you can use BeautifulSoup to parse whatever it is that you are after. See [Selenium with Python](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) for further help on how to get started.